# Is there an ICS ROM for the Galaxy Tab 10.1 that has camera support?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, camera, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I'm keen to upgrade my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to Android 4, ICS. My Tab is already rooted and running 3.2.

However, it seems most ICS ROMs, for some reason, don't support the camera, which is a deal breaker.

As time goes on, it seems that ROMs and the places they are available multiply and it gets harder and harder to keep track of what's the latest and where to get it.

So is there an ICS ROM for the Galaxy Tab 10.1 with camera support? If not, where should I be paying attention in order to be made aware of it?

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question, as I don't want to start any controversies, and it seems that this question can be taken differently than I had intended.

Comment: Have you checked http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1050

Comment: I fail to see any controversy in this question. Rather, I voted the question up. It's a pretty simple yes/no answer at a high-level, and any more detailed discussion should hopefully provide a positive answer.

Comment: The canonical question for finding Custom ROMs is here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ROM with camera support is [now available](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1656550&page=65). I found it on the XDA Developers forum.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot lock down a feature list, and I don't have a tablet to try it on, but I've found that the [AOKP ROMs](http://aokp.co/index.php/news) are pretty far along. I think it may have camera support, but you'll have to let me know.

Comment: I just recently sold my Galaxy Tab 10.1, but I kept up withe Roman's AOKP ROMs. The latest build (37 I think, as of just a few days ago) didn't have camera support still, but oh well. I'm sure they will get it working soon.

Comment: [Build 40](http://aokp.co/index.php/releases/_/build-40-r26) is out now, but good info. Not likely to have support then :/ Hopefully someone else has tried this new one?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung have started rolling out the official ICS ROM now (at least it was applied to mine recently), I'd be surprised if that doesn't support the camera.